# Can Parse Push Notifications be targeted to a specific iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I see in Parse's documents that a push notification can be targeted to a specific device (iOS, Android, etc.). I would like to target a notification to iOS device users with a specific iOS (iOS 8). Can this be accomplished, or are we limited to targeting to a general device family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding an osVersion field to your _Installation class, and then query against it. When you save the installation on the device you could set this field.\

iOS code example:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[@"global"];
    currentInstallation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
    currentInstallation[@"osVersion"] = [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion;
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. so if the user changes their iOS, the installation would be resaved since the app will have to be relaunched from terminated?

Comment: You can check everytime the app opens up whether from terminated or not depending on where you run your code. Realistically if they update their OS it would run from terminated anyway. If you want to save API calls, you can decide to resave only when the osVersion changes.

Comment: How would you know the osVersion changed? Would you store it in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: You could compare it to the locally stored PFInstallation currentInstallation, or store it in userdefaults.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I don't understand yet how or where PFInstallation is locally stored though, since I just started looking at this yesterday..

Comment: added ios code that would save the OS version. A lot of PFObject information is cached locally to include PFUser currentUser, and PFInstallation currentInstallation. You can optionally fetch(pull) and save(push) this information as you see fit to parse.com

Comment: That's great, thank you. Following up on our earlier conversation thread, is there a way to resave only when the os version changes, as you mentioned above? Or do I need to save the current installation in the background each time the app is launched (since I register for remote notifications with each app launch as suggested)?

Comment: Given this method is the only place to get the deviceToken it would make the most sense to save it at this time with the appropriate osVersion.